# Add new attribute to the existing JSON array in Node

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, attributes

I want to insert one or more attributes into the existing JSON. Here's the basic format.

```
var resultData = {
        "result" : "OK",
        "data" : [
            {"name1" : "value1"},
            {"name2" : "value2"}
        ]
    };
```

And I want to insert {"name3" : "value3"} into the end of the data field. The result should look like this.

```
var resultData = {
        "result" : "OK",
        "data" : [
            {"name1" : "value1"},
            {"name2" : "value2"},
            {"name3" : "value3"}
        ]
    };
```

How do I do this? I know how to add an attribute to the resultData or resultData.result or resultData.data.name1 or etc. However, I couldn't find a way to add an attribute to the resultData.data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
resultData.data[3] = {"name4" : "value4"}
```

That would add a new element on the 4th position.
And like Sigorilla just answered before me, `.push()` will always add it one the end of your object.

You don't need to do `resultData["data"].push()` though, as you can just use `resultData.data.push()` I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `push()`: `resultData["data"].push({"name3": "value3"});`